# New rows are locked by select on PostgreSQL replica

Tags: postgresql, replication, locking, aws

have a strange trouble with getting new rows on replica on PostgreSQL on AWS.
I have master database on AWS with constant flow inserts/updates not with big rate.
And these changes are replicated through WAL streaming to replica db.
When i do query on replica to get new fresh rows written to master all works fine.
When i do long read query on this replica, i stop getting new data in other transactions to same replica,
though i still can get data before long scan transaction started.

I tried to look at locks and pg_activity table and could not get any meaningful information about appeared locks.
From knowhelege i have, to lock some rows PG have to lock resource in AccessExclusive mode.
Locks i see in table which made by long query on replica all are in AccessShare mode and no other exlusive locks are there.
From my perspective, this looks like that when i do long query on replica new rows imported by WAL parsing are getting locked for reading.

What other ways or tools can i use to understand problem and find the cause?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html#USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.Configuration

Here are commands and text description i used for debug:

1. Trying to query replica locks without any long running queries:

```
SELECT lock.locktype,
       lock.relation::regclass,
       lock.mode,
       lock.transactionid AS tid,
       lock.virtualtransaction AS vtid,
       lock.pid,
       lock.granted
FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks LOCK
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_database db ON db.oid = lock.database
WHERE (db.datname = 'DB'
       OR db.datname IS NULL)
  AND NOT lock.pid = pg_backend_pid()
ORDER BY lock.pid;

  locktype  | relation |     mode      | tid | vtid | pid | granted
------------+----------+---------------+-----+------+-----+---------
 virtualxid |          | ExclusiveLock |     | 1/0  | 352 | t
(1 row)

geting only virtualxid of select locks query
```

2. Running long scan/index scan query and looking for locks, activity table:

run long query:

```
SELECT id,
       created_at
FROM tbl
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 10000000;
```

after that any short query like below stops giving new rows
updated on master and replicated to replica where all queries are executed:

```
SELECT id,
       created_at
FROM tbl
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

trying to find locking reason:

```
SELECT lock.locktype,
       lock.relation::regclass,
       lock.mode,
       lock.transactionid AS tid,
       lock.virtualtransaction AS vtid,
       lock.pid,
       lock.granted
FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks LOCK
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_database db ON db.oid = lock.database
WHERE (db.datname = 'DB'
       OR db.datname IS NULL)
  AND NOT lock.pid = pg_backend_pid()
ORDER BY lock.pid;

  locktype  |                      relation                      |      mode       | tid |   vtid    |  pid  | granted
------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----+-----------+-------+---------
 virtualxid |                                                    | ExclusiveLock   |     | 1/0       |   352 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_001"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_002"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_003"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_004"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_005"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_005"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_007"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_008"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_009"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_010"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_011"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_012"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_013"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "PK_tbl"                                           | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "tbl"                                              | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 virtualxid |                                                    | ExclusiveLock   |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_014"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_015"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_016"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_017"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
 relation   | "IX_tbl_018"                                       | AccessShareLock |     | 5/1231551 | 24973 | t
```

```
SELECT
    pid,
    backend_start,
    query_start,
    state_change,
    wait_event_type,
    wait_event,
    query,
    backend_type
FROM
    pg_stat_activity;


-[ RECORD 1 ]---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid             | 461
backend_start   | 2023-03-04 07:17:45.420192+00
query_start     | 2023-03-05 14:48:19.722021+00
state_change    | 2023-03-05 14:48:19.722038+00
wait_event_type | Client
wait_event      | ClientRead
query           | SELECT 1
backend_type    | client backend
-[ RECORD 2 ]---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid             | 28583
backend_start   | 2023-03-04 14:29:51.138626+00
query_start     | 2023-03-05 14:48:21.916923+00
state_change    | 2023-03-05 14:48:21.916971+00
wait_event_type | Client
wait_event      | ClientRead
query           | COMMIT
backend_type    | client backend
-[ RECORD 3 ]---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid             | 28584
backend_start   | 2023-03-04 14:29:52.091085+00
query_start     | 2023-03-05 14:47:52.314253+00
state_change    | 2023-03-05 14:47:52.314281+00
wait_event_type | Client
wait_event      | ClientRead
query           | ROLLBACK
backend_type    | client backend
-[ RECORD 4 ]---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid             | 22783
backend_start   | 2023-03-05 14:31:10.44282+00
query_start     | 2023-03-05 14:48:22.722693+00
state_change    | 2023-03-05 14:48:22.722695+00
wait_event_type |
wait_event      |
query           | SELECT                                                                    +
                |     pid,                                                                  +
                |     backend_start,                                                        +
                |     query_start,                                                          +
                |     state_change,                                                         +
                |     wait_event_type,                                                      +
                |     wait_event,                                                           +
                |     query,                                                                +
                |     backend_type                                                          +
                | FROM pg_stat_activity;
backend_type    | client backend
-[ RECORD 5 ]---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid             | 23849
backend_start   | 2023-03-05 14:47:55.602716+00
query_start     | 2023-03-05 14:48:11.454558+00
state_change    | 2023-03-05 14:48:11.454561+00
wait_event_type | Client
wait_event      | ClientWrite
query           | select id, created_at from tbl order by created_at desc limit 10000000;
backend_type    | client backend
[ RECORD 6 ]---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid             | 373
backend_start   | 2023-03-04 07:17:44.493326+00
query_start     |
state_change    |
wait_event_type | Activity
wait_event      | RecoveryWalStream
query           |
backend_type    | startup
-[ RECORD 7 ]---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid             | 383
backend_start   | 2023-03-04 07:17:44.612868+00
query_start     |
state_change    |
wait_event_type | Activity
wait_event      | BgWriterHibernate
query           |
backend_type    | background writer
-[ RECORD 8 ]---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid             | 382
backend_start   | 2023-03-04 07:17:44.613552+00
query_start     |
state_change    |
wait_event_type | Activity
wait_event      | CheckpointerMain
query           |
backend_type    | checkpointer
-[ RECORD 9 ]---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid             | 1065
backend_start   | 2023-03-04 07:18:49.420368+00
query_start     |
state_change    |
wait_event_type | Activity
wait_event      | WalReceiverMain
query           |
backend_type    | walreceiver
```

Postgres config:

here i compare settings of local PG where all works well (first value) and replica (second value)

```
'archive_mode': ('off', 'on'),
'archive_timeout': ('0', '300'),
'autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor': ('0.1', '0.05'),
'autovacuum_naptime': ('60', '15'),
'autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit': ('-1', '200'),
'autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor': ('0.2', '0.1'),
'checkpoint_completion_target': ('0.5', '0.9'),
'data_checksums': ('off', 'on'),
'effective_cache_size': ('524288', '486132'),
'huge_pages': ('try', 'on'),
'idle_in_transaction_session_timeout': ('0', '86400000'),
'jit': ('on', 'off'),
'listen_addresses': ('localhost', '*'),
'log_autovacuum_min_duration': ('-1', '10000'),
'log_checkpoints': ('off', 'on'),
'log_file_mode': ('0600', '0644'),
'log_rotation_age': ('1440', '60'),
'logging_collector': ('off', 'on'),
'maintenance_work_mem': ('65536', '127510'),
'max_connections': ('100', '5000'),
'max_replication_slots': ('10', '20'),
'max_stack_depth': ('2048', '6144'),
'max_standby_archive_delay': ('30000', '100000'),
'max_standby_streaming_delay': ('30000', '60000'),
'max_wal_senders': ('10', '20'),
'max_wal_size': ('1024', '2048'),
'max_worker_processes': ('8', '32'),
'min_wal_size': ('80', '192'),
'pg_stat_statements.max': ('', '5000'),
'pg_stat_statements.save': ('', 'on'),
'pg_stat_statements.track': ('', 'top'),
'pg_stat_statements.track_planning': ('', 'off'),
'pg_stat_statements.track_utility': ('', 'on'),
'server_version_num': ('130009', '130007'),
'shared_buffers': ('16384', '243066'),
'tcp_keepalives_count': ('9', '2'),
'tcp_keepalives_idle': ('7200', '300'),
'tcp_keepalives_interval': ('75', '30'),
'track_activity_query_size': ('1024', '4096'),
'track_functions': ('none', 'pl'),
'track_io_timing': ('off', 'on'),
'transaction_read_only': ('off', 'on'),
'unix_socket_permissions': ('0777', '0700'),
'vacuum_cost_page_miss': ('10', '5'),
'wal_buffers': ('512', '7595'),
'wal_compression': ('off', 'on'),
'wal_keep_size': ('0', '2048'),
'wal_receiver_timeout': ('60000', '30000'),
'wal_segment_size': ('16777216', '67108864'),
'wal_sender_timeout': ('60000', '30000')
```

Update:

tried to check views `pg_stat_database_conflicts` and `pg_stat_replication`.

from `pg_stat_database_conflicts` I see that there are "`confl_snapshot`" conflicts.
According to [the article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/), the most likely reason for it is "*Snapshot replication conflicts*".
There is also a [topic on recovery conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699304/what-causes-data-on-a-read-replica-to-be-an-old-snapshot-and-cause-conflict).

As I got from this topic and [the article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/what-hot_standby_feedback-in-postgresql-really-does/), I can eliminate from replica queries cancelling by tuning
`hot_standby_feedback` parameter, thus making the master keep data used by the query on standby. And if this query never ends dead tuples on master will never be deleted.

Also, in my queries i did not see any replay_lsn lags, but saw confl_snapshots conflicts:

```
DB=> select * from pg_stat_database_conflicts where datname='DB';
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+--------
datid            | 16416
datname          | DB
confl_tablespace | 0
confl_lock       | 0
confl_snapshot   | 4
confl_bufferpin  | 0
confl_deadlock   | 0


DB=> select * from pg_stat_replication;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+-------------
pid              | 399
usesysid         | 16396
usename          | rdsrepladmin
application_name | walreceiver
client_addr      |
client_hostname  |
client_port      |
backend_start    |
backend_xmin     |
state            |
sent_lsn         |
write_lsn        |
flush_lsn        |
replay_lsn       |
write_lag        |
flush_lag        |
replay_lag       |
sync_priority    |
sync_state       |
reply_time       |
-[ RECORD 2 ]----+-------------
pid              | 398
usesysid         | 16396
usename          | rdsrepladmin
application_name | walreceiver
client_addr      |
client_hostname  |
client_port      |
backend_start    |
backend_xmin     |
state            |
sent_lsn         |
write_lsn        |
flush_lsn        |
replay_lsn       |
write_lag        |
flush_lag        |
replay_lag       |
sync_priority    |
sync_state       |
reply_time       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no locks; this is probably only a [replication conflict](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/streaming-replication-conflicts-in-postgresql/). If you look at `pg_stat_replication` on the primary side, you should see that `replay_lsn` starts lagging when changes are no longer replayed on the standby. You can prevent that by reducing `max_standby_streaming_delay` on the standby, but only at the price of having queries on the standby canceled.

Comment: Question still unclear to me if i can get fresh data on standby turning `hot_standby_feedback` on and setting `max_standby_delay` to some small value. Logic says that if we tell master to keep the WAL version compliant to standby`s WAL during queries last, standby may apply got WAL without conflicts caused by VACUUM. These are my untested thoughts at the moment.

Comment: It should get rid of snapshot conflicts. But there are others.

Comment: so it is for everyone to decide what steps to take, use another source of data,
replicas with different `max_standby_delay` settings or face other conflicts.
Me personally cheerful to get help from community, thanks!